# Not displaying any articles on a custom made file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I have created the file **latest.php** in the public_html so that when I go to **www.domain.com/latest.php** it will show me the latest articles. Sadly, nothing of the posts came up. Later, I will sort them with other ways (mostly based on custom fields).

This is my **latest.php** file (I removed any styling for better understanding)

```
<?php include("wp-load.php"); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

**AND HERE IS WHAT I COPY-PASTED FROM MY INDEX.PHP THAT IS WORKING**

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <a title="" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endwhile; // End the loop ?>

<?php posts_nav_link(' &#183; ', 'previous page', 'next page'); ?>
```

My question is how can I make it possible to show the latest articles with pagination ? **wp-load.php** , **wp_head** and **get_header** are loaded correctly.

Should I use an entire different method for my task? If yes, which one?

Comment: Why do you want to re-implement a feature, that is part of the Wordpress core functionalities? The normal article view displays the latest articles; but if you really want to do that by yourself implement it to the theme. See also: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-recent-posts-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wordpress does not works this way... if you want to make a custom page. create a new template page in the themes folder and then (from back end) create a new page and assign that template to that page.. this way you can put you custom code in the template file and wordpress can process it

Comment: Hello, can you give me a code example on how to assign the page with template ?

Comment: first create a new template file read this http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates the you can find the option to assign template in right side of the page when you create a new page